# Riemann implies Lebesgue integrablility on $\mathbb{R}^n$, prove $f(x)$ continuous at x where $g(x)=G(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times[a_n,b_n] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable. Prove that is $f$ Lebesgue integrable.

Proof:
$$Q:= [a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times [a_n,b_n].$$
For simple function $g = \sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \chi_{Q_j}$ ,where are $Q_j$ parallelepipeds
contained in $Q$, Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide. Call such function as step function. Let choose sequence $P_k$ partition of cuboid $Q$ that is $P_{k+1}$ subdivision of partition $P_k$ and diameter of $P_k \to 0$ when $k \to \infty$. Let $$Q_{j}^{k}, \quad 1 \leq j \leq M_k,$$ be a partition cuboid of $P_k$ and let $$m_{j}^{k} = \inf_{Q_{j}^{k}}f, \quad M_{j}^{k} = \sup_{Q_{j}^{k}}f.$$

Define functions $g_k, G_k$ on $Q$ in this way: $$g_k :=m_{j}^{k}, \quad G_k :=M_{j}^{k},$$ for $x \in Q_{j}^{k}$. Now we have lower Darboux sum of function $f$ with regard to $P_k$:
$$s_k = \int_{Q} g_k \, dx = \int_{Q}g_k \, dm_n,$$ Riemann and Lebesgue integral step function $g_k$ coincide. Same conclusion for upper Darboux sum
$$\int_{Q}G_k \, dx = \int_{Q}G_k \, dm_n.$$

We have $g_k$ increasing and $G_k$ decreasing, so $g_k \rightarrow g$, $G_k \rightarrow G$ where $g(x),G(x)$ are measurable. $f$ is Riemann integrabile implies $$\int_{Q} g_k \, dm_n 
\to I = \int_{Q} f(x) \, dx \text{ and } \int_{Q} G_k \, dm_n \to I = \int_{Q} f(x) \,dx.$$

From theorem dominated convergence

$$I = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{Q}G_k \, dm_n = \int_{Q}G \, dm_n$$

$$I = \lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{Q}g_k \, dm_n = \int_{Q}g \, dm_n,$$

so that

$$\int_{Q} (G-g) dm_n = 0 \text{ and } (G-g) \geq 0.$$

So $G(x)=g(x)$ a.e. and  $g\leq f \leq G$.

$g(x),G(x)$ are Lebesgue integrable. $\Box$

$\textbf{Question: Prove that is function $f$ continuous at every point x where g(x)= G(x)? } $

Comment: First try to prove it is a measurable function. then approximated by upper and lower step functions........

Comment: @user1729 this is a first question!!!

Comment: I do not think that this question should be closed. The OP, instead of editing the original question ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882519/darboux-integrable-f-continuous-at-x-where-gx-gx?noredirect=1#comment1821536_882519)), has started a new question telling us what they've tried. In my eye's this counts as "telling us what they're tried". We should not penalise users because their understanding of English is poor.

Comment: (But @Anonymous, you should have [edited](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/882519/edit) your original post rather than starting this new one.)